# Future Perfect continuous question

Tags: perfect-aspect

Wondering if it is correct to use Future Perfect continuous time in the sentence:
"We will have been eating by 8pm tomorrow, so plz come at 9pm."

Or it is better to us Future Perfect:
"We will have eaten by 8pm tomorrow, so plz come at 9pm."

I'd grateful if someone explains what option to use and why.
Thank you.

Comment: Note that writing "plz" as a text-speakeasy abbr8shn for *please* may be perceived as childish, lazy, or disrespectful by some readers, so you would be well advised to write it out in full, ***S.V.P.***

Answer (score 2):

I am not a native speaker, but I've been learning the language since quite long, so I'll try to answer your question.
*If you mean that by 8 pm tomorrow you will finish eating, you should say - We will have eaten by 8 pm tomorrow.
*If you mean that at 8 pm you will be in the process of eating, you should say - We will be eating at 9 pm tomorrow.

As for Future Perfect Continuous, it is used when an action 
1)is still in the process 
2)we know for how long it is in the process so far.

F.e. In March, I will have been working in this company for one year. 
1) I am still working there
2) We know for how long

Answer (score 0):

> "We will have been eating by 8pm tomorrow, so please come at 9pm."

This sentence is not appropriate. Because the continuous aspect **‘eating‘** shows that even after 8 pm we will continue eating.

> "We will have been eating by 8pm tomorrow, so please come at 9pm."

This is appropriate because the perfect aspect **'eaten'** shows that our eating will be completed by 8 pm.